# Webpack Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[\n\r\u2028\u2029]/: Regular expression too large

Tags: node.js, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, react-scripts

Not sure what happened, all of a sudden Webpack is throwing the following error on the dev server on npm start. Nothing changed in the webpack config for React Scripts:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[\n\r\u2028\u2029]/: Regular expression too large

The error is coming from chunk.js, which is not something I'm touching during development and its with the following line:

var reNewLine = /[\n\r\u2028\u2029]/g;

I've tried removing and reinstalling node modules, upgraded downgraded React and react-scripts and react dom, I've tried switching node versions with nvm, and I've tried reverting back to an earlier branch commit where I knew the app was loading fine. Nothing works. Was working on app components and then this error just started popping up randomly.

Help!!! Lol

**UPDATE**

So I tried pulling down a earlier version of my codebase from Github on a specific commit from a month ago, one that I know was in fact working before I pushed it, and I'm still getting the same error from webpack, which tells me this is an environment issue. I've tried cleaning the npm cache, deleting package-lock.json and package.json, reinstalling node_modules. I've tried changing the node version with nvm, using a whole other different version of node, still getting the same error from webpack in Chrome.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of Chrome console error]

**UPDATE 2**

I downgraded my versions of react, react-dom, and react scripts.

"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1"

Now I'm getting the same error from webpack (Regex pattern too large), but for a different Regex pattern. Have no idea what these regexes are for, not something I wrote.

[image]

UPDATE 3

So I confirmed this is an issue when doing development in Chrome Version 95. I pulled my codebase down onto another computer that had Version 91 of Chrome installed. My app worked fine. As soon as I upgraded, the regex error started appearing on that computer as well. This is a breaking change for webpack with the newest version of Chrome.

Oddly enough, that same regex works when I launch a skeleton version of the app from months ago. Makes no sense.

Comment: did you upgrade node?

Comment: @flakerimi, I tried using a more recent version of node, but the highest I can use is Node 14, because node-sass@4.14.1, doesn't have compatibility for 15-17. I'm using NVM to switch between node versions. Should I upgrade my node-sass version?

Comment: try different version of node, lower.

Comment: You could downgrade chrome version. But I was too lazy to do that and just installed firefox where it works

Comment: I downgraded Chrome to 91, and it works. But Its still not working on 95 or above for Chrome. This issue is going to break a lot of React apps.